# EF save to Context but not to Datasource

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, objectcontext

Having a EF Context and a Testenity I want to get the following test to work.

```
TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity() { Name = "Hello World" };
context.TestEntities.AddObject(testEntity);
// missing Code
Assert.AreEqual(1, context.TestEntities.Count(), "Entity not in context!");
```

I know that it works with SaveChanges() but I do **not want to save** the Entity to the **datasource**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity() { Name = "Hello World" };
context.TestEntities.AddObject(testEntity);

var entitiesInOSM = context.ObjectStateManager.
        GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged).
        Where(ent => ent.Entity is TestEntity).
        Select(ent => ent.Entity as TestEntity);

Assert.AreEqual(1, entitiesInOSM.Count(), "Entity not in context!");
```

Comment: this works. but doesn't look nice. 
isn't there a way to get a LINQ query against the context without saving?
from TestEntity t in context.TestEntities ....

Comment: No. Whenever you execute a query against the context the underlying provider gets queried. That you don't want in your case.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to achieve with your test?  All this test would achieve here is to Assert the underlying Entity Framework ContextObject which is a pointless test for you.

If you're trying to then run additional tests for which the ObjectContext is a dependency you can mock out the ObjectContext with an interface.  We create our own custom IObjectContext interface we extract from the T4 generated ContextObject off our model.

Comment: ok it is not really a test case. 

what i want to achieve is to add entities to the context and not to save them to the database but query the context for added entities before saving!!